# Can't make the text middle and centered

Tags: html, css

```
.css {
    background: highlight none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 10px;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 10px;
    font-size:10px
}
```

And `height` & `width` and `font-size` can't less or more than `10px`.

```
<div class="css">4</div>
```

Do you have solutions for this?

Comment: centered horizontally only or both?

Comment: Vertically, you could also center your content using a container that has a defined width and center the inner div using `margin: 0 auto`

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to do this is to just set `line-height` equal to `height` of element.

```css
.css {
  background: highlight;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="css">4</div>
```

Other method is to use `Flexbox` and set `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center`.

```css
.css {
  background: highlight;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="css">4</div>
```